# Font problem with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, libertine

When trying to compile my `.tex` file using the `xelatex` command in TeXmaker (with MiKTeX), I get this error message:

> ! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
>   !
>   ! The font "Linux Libertine O" cannot be found.
>   !
>   ! See the fontspec documentation for further
>   information.

I have looked at the `fontspec` documentation, but haven't found anything helpful.

My `.tex` file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\section{Unicode support}

\subsection{English}
All human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights.

\subsection{Íslenska}
Hver maður er borinn frjáls og jafn öðrum að virðingu og réttindum.

\section{Ligatures}
\fontspec[Ligatures={Common, Historical}]{Linux Libertine O Italic}
Questo è strano assai!

\section{Numerals}
\fontspec[Numbers={OldStyle}]{Linux Libertine O}Old style: 1234567\\
\fontspec[Numbers={Lining}]{Linux Libertine O}Lining: 1234567

\end{document}
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I could fix this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: Do you have that font installed? I guess that you are using Windows. But that font is default on Linux.

Comment: @Sigur - OP is using MikTeX, so Windows not having that font is most likely.  Perhaps [download it](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/index.php?id=91&L=1)?

Comment: Try with `\usepackage{libertine}` (but make sure you have an up-to-date MiKTeX). Leave out the `\setmainfont` and `\fontspec` instructions, first.

Comment: Ok, I have tried again and everything works fine! So the solution is to replace \setmainfont and \fontspec by \usepackage{libertine}, as per egreg.

Comment: @ben Usually any TeX editor has no role to play in any  font issue or TeX errors its just a frontend (GUI), `.tex file` is input to `latex` engine and it outputs `.log` and `.pdf`.

Comment: Your original example works fine in MiKTeX if the libertine package is installed.  It seems the automatic installation for MiKTeX doesn't install libertine if fontspec needs the otf fonts.

Comment: If you had used \setmainfont{LinLibertine_R.otf} (i.e., used a font file name), MiKTeX would have offered to install the libertine package.

Answer (score 9):

Choosing the right name for a font is sometimes hard. The specification

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
```

should work if you have the font among the system fonts. However XeTeX is able to use also fonts that reside in the TeX tree and are not in the system fonts.

In the case of Linux Libertine, the call should be something like

```
\setmainfont
      [ Ligatures = TeX,
        Extension = .otf,
        SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
        UprightFont    = *_R,
        ItalicFont     = *_RI,
        BoldFont       = *_B,
        BoldItalicFont = *_BI,
      ] {LinLibertine}
```

The package `libertine` frees you from this burden. Check the package documentation to see what options can be passed to the call

```
\usepackage[...]{libertine}
```

where `...` stands for zero or more option, such as `oldstyle` or `lining` to choose between the two styles for figures.

Comment: In order to get `\setmainfont` to work with the TeX font, I had to substitute the following two lines for the ones given: `BoldFont = *_RB,` and `BoldItalicFont = *_RBI,`