# Currency formatting with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

This is just an oddity. I use siuniutx to format currencies (with some spacing every three digits, and to 2 decimals irrespective of input). However the prefix does not like the usual \pounds symbol (converting this to $). A straight £ works fine. I just wondered why this is the case.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
The \pounds\ pounds macro behaves as expected

And this is \pounds40434.5345

The dollar prefix works fine: \SI[round-precision=2,round-mode=places,round-integer-to-decimal]{34324}[\$]{}

But the pounds prefix is imperialistic: \SI[round-precision=2,round-mode=places,round-integer-to-decimal]{34324}[\pounds]{}

But straight pound sign is ok: \SI[round-precision=2,round-mode=places,round-integer-to-decimal]{34324}[£]{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You get an pound symbol with `pdflatex`

Comment: But not xelatex, at least here

Comment: If you are using XeLaTeX leave out the `libertine` package then use the settings in @egreg's answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105970/font-problem-with-xelatex . He mentions that they should be equivalent however I always had various other problems as you have here.

Comment: At least here replacing libertine with \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O} yields the same outcome albeit with a non-italic $. Using a completely different font package (\usepackage[lining,proportional]{ebgaramond}) again yields the $

Comment: @AubreyBlumsohn Use egreg's font name. There is a difference

Comment: @percusse - when I do that I just get "font not found", so can't try that approach. - I suspect because those fonts are not default in Windows and not part of the Tex install.

Comment: Further --  If I load no specific font package or font at all (just Fontspec by itself yielding the default which seems to be LMRoman12) I get the same effect. I am more inclined to think that the bug (if there is one) is in siunitx, and that for some reason it manifests only in XeLaTex?

Comment: Historically speaking, it would be more imperialistic if all currency symbols were converted to £.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For historical reasons due to the fact that usually the `\mathrm` font is OT1 encoded, the command `\mathsterling` does `\mathit{\mathchar"7024}}` (that is it uses the dollar sign, which in the italic OT1 font is a pound sign).

Fix the wrong definition.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\renewcommand{\mathsterling}{\mathrm{\mathchar"70A3}}

\begin{document}
The \pounds\ pounds macro behaves as expected

And this is \pounds40434.5345

The dollar prefix works fine:
\SI[round-precision=2,round-mode=places,round-integer-to-decimal]{34324}[\$]{}

But the pounds prefix is imperialistic:
\SI[round-precision=2,round-mode=places,round-integer-to-decimal]{34324}[\pounds]{}

But straight pound sign is ok:
\SI[round-precision=2,round-mode=places,round-integer-to-decimal]{34324}[£]{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can propose a `\Pounds` macro, with a (numerical) optional argument: if there's no argument, it is the same a `\pounds`; if there's a number it adds a formatted number, preceded by an unbreakable thin space:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\Pounds{o}{%
\pounds\IfNoValueTF{#1}%
{\relax}{\,\num[round-precision=2,round-mode=places,round-integer-to-decimal]{#1}}}

\begin{document}

But the pounds prefix is imperialistic:
\Pounds[34324]

\Pounds34324

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, that's a neat macro (and it works, and I'll use it). But it is essentially bypassing the standard prefixing mechanism in siunitx, and doesn't explain why that mechanism doesn't work for \pounds (in any font tried) but does for £, and why that failure is only manifest in XeLaTex.

Comment: I have the same problem in compiling with `pdflatex`, using `fourier`, `ebgaramond`, `erewhon`. The problem doesn't exist only with `latin modern` and `computer modern`. I would think the problem is in the `\pounds` macro itself (using a specific TeX encoding?). Anyway, the prefix system doesn't add a thin space between currency symbol and number, as it should.

Comment: I've just discovered  the problem disappeats with this code: `\SI[round-precision=2,round-mode=places,round-integer-to-decimal]{34324}[\text{\pounds}]{}`.

Comment: (Sorry for the off-topic remark but:) Thank you @Bernard! I've been trying to get the rupee-sign (₹) prefixed through the `SI` but drew a literal blank no matter how I tried defining it --- yet ₹ worked well outside the `SI` -command. Surrounding it with `\text{}` did the trick!

Comment: (Continuing the off-topic remark:) Another way of fixing it was to inform the `SI` command that it wasn't in math-mode. For instance by using the option `detect-mode=true` for `\SI`. Then I expect `\pounds` would've worked as well? At least ₹ did.

Comment: Yes, I think so.